# complicated non-standard menu layout and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-repeat

AngularJS' ng-repeat is simple especially if the dom you are creating are consistent.

I can't figure out how to make this though. I have 5 buttons and this is how I was planning to declare the variable

```
$scope.sidebarMenus = [
  { menuName : 'Button 1', active : false, width : 'medium-6'},
  { menuName : 'Button 2', active : false, width : 'medium-6'},
  { menuName : 'Button 3', active : false, width : 'medium-6'},
  { menuName : 'Button 4', active : false, width : 'medium-6'},
  { menuName : 'Button 5', active : false, width : 'medium-12'}
];
```

If you noticed, there are 3 rows. I can ng-repeat on an array with length of 3 but the inside ng-repeat will break since they'll be separated. Maybe I'm wrong.

```
<div class="small-12 large-4 columns sidebar">
<div class="row">
    <a class="medium-6 columns menu-item button">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page-add size-36"></i>
            <p class="size-12">Button 1</p>
        </div>
        <span class="custom-border-bottom"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="medium-6 columns menu-item button">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page-edit size-36"></i>
            <p class="size-12">Button 2</p>
        </div>
        <span class="custom-border-bottom"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <a class="medium-6 columns menu-item button">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page size-36"></i>
            <p class="size-12">Button 3</p>
        </div>
        <span class="custom-border-bottom"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="medium-6 columns menu-item button">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page size-36"></i>
            <p class="size-12">Button 4</p>
        </div>
        <span class="custom-border-bottom"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <a class="medium-12 columns menu-item button">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page size-36"></i>
            <p class="size-12">Button 5</p>
        </div>
        <span class="custom-border-bottom"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="small-12 large-8 columns content">
any text goes in here in the content any text goes in here in the content any text goes in here in the content any text goes in here in the content any text goes in here in the content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: those are objects right? use can use a higher `<div ng-repeat="button in sidebarMenus"> your code </div>`

Comment: That will not work since that will create 5 divs.

Comment: are you sure you need to separate these into 3 `"row"`s? They should float naturally due to the grid system if you just have 1 row.

Comment: oh my bad. i missed that there was no `div` in between.

Comment: maybe you can create a directive. which does this for you.

Comment: btw folks, I edited the code above. Please reload. That code produces this kind of sidebar menu - http://i.imgur.com/ZAZUSBr.png

Comment: @AustinGreco that's how our designer designed the sidebar menu. See the image I posted recently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just `ng-repeat` as expected, and have the grid system wrap the columns correctly. If there is 6+6, it will wrap down to the next line automatically. You shouldn't need to manually place the row divs.

```
<div class="row">
    <a ng-repeat="menu in sidebarMenus" class="{{menu.width}} columns menu-item button">
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="show-for-large-up fi-page-add size-36"></i>
            <p class="size-12">{{menu.menuName}}</p>
        </div>
        <span class="custom-border-bottom"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see three ways to solve this:

1. You simplify your HTML and try to do the layout with CSS only, using some clever widths and `inline-block` display or any grid like style. I don't think the name of your CSS classes should be part of your model anyway. At best a weight like `1` or `2` (separation of concerns).
2. Create a custom directive `grid-buttons` that takes your buttons list in input and prepare the layout dynamically.
3. Structure your model so it is easily reflected in your DOM. One array per row, such as:

   ```
    $scope.sidebarMenus = [
      [
        { menuName : 'Button 1', active : false},
        { menuName : 'Button 2', active : false}
      ],
      [
        { menuName : 'Button 3', active : false},
        { menuName : 'Button 4', active : false}
      ],
      [
        { menuName : 'Button 5', active : false}
      ]
    ];
   ```

   (In which case I would recommend using `flexbox` styling)